# Module not found in prestashop new module install

Tags: module, prestashop

I created a module, when i tried to install it, an error occuried "Module not found"
I created a folder storedisplay in which i created a file storedisplay.php and this is the code

```
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
exit;

class StoreDisplay extends Module
{
public function __construct()
{
$this->name = 'StoreDispaly';
$this->tab = 'Test';
$this->version = 1.0;
$this->author = 'infobia';


parent::__construct();

$this->displayName = $this->l('infobia store display');
$this->description = $this->l('display a store listbox.');
}



public function install()
{
if (parent::install() == false)// OR !$this->registerHook('displayStore'))
return false;
return true;
}


public function hookTop($params)
{
global $smarty;

return $this->display(__FILE__, 'infobiastoredisplay.tpl');
}




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module name is misspelled here:

```
$this->name = 'StoreDispaly';
```